# Design a way for multiple and single group mapped to a Role?

Tags: database-design, sql, relational-database

Currently I am trying to setup a relationship between user groups and roles.

I am trying to satisfy:

> 1. Multiple roles apply to single group
> 2. multiple groups can have same role
> 3. multiple groups with single role.

I have a Group Table with `RoleID` and `GroupName` and a Role table with `RoleID` and `RoleName`. I am able to satisfy 1 and 2 fine but I am stuck on 3.
Say currently I have Group 1 mapped to Roles 1&2. Group 2 mapped to Roles 2. Now lets say I have Role 3 which is ONLY available if I have Group 1 and 2 together.

I dont think my current design can handle checking if a Role is only available if the user belongs to 2 groups vs 1. Is there some SQL I can do or some way to construct the tables?

Ex:

> Group Table:
>   Group1:RoleID1
>   Group2:RoleID2
>   Group3:RoleID3
>   HOW TO REPRESENT GROUP1+2 MAP TO RoleID3?

Role Table:

> RoleID1:Group1
>   RoleID2:Group2
>   RoleID3: Group3
>   RoleID3:NEED GROUPS 1 AND 2 TOGETHER

For my example above, i can have a Group that maps directly to a Role OR 2 Groups maps to the same Role. So Role3 can be available for a User with Group3 OR Groups1+2. I am not sure how to differentiate the 2. Will i need to redesign the datatables or have update to my SQL?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "apply", "have", "mapped". Please also explain in more detail what the relationship between groups and roles can be. Your three points are not clear.

Comment: Hi. So here's the situation. I have a list of users who can belong to multiple User Groups. Each User Group can have one or more Roles, and each Role is mapped to a Permission table (like "Writer" Role can have Permission of 2,3,4 etc.).

For example, right now I made it that UserGroup have a format of RoleID:UserGroupName. and in Role table i have RoleID:RoleName. This doesn't work if a situation of UserGroup1+UserGroup2 = Role3 since i am doing 1 to 1 map. I am not sure if there's some query magic i can do or a way to design the tables that way? Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. In particular the examples. Please improve the format of the examples.